# How to declare a function that returns an iterable

Tags: swift, generics

I have a function that is currently defined as:

```
public func mappingsWithElementId(elementId:String) -> [Mapping] {
    return _mappings.lazy.map({ $1 }).filter({ $0.elementId == elementId })
}
```

I would like to change it so that rather than return an array, it just returns a (lazy) object that can be iterated, i.e., a `CollectionType<Mapping>` that the caller can then use however is appropriate.

Now, I can use:

```
public func mappingsWithElementId(elementId:String) -> LazyFilterCollection<LazyMapCollection<[String:Mapping], Mapping>> {
    return _mappings.lazy.map({ $1 }).filter({ $0.elementId == elementId })
}
```

But that's way overly specific for what I'm attempting to do (which is just tell the caller that it's something that can be iterated to get `Mapping`s.  And as I cascade more functions of a similar nature it just gets uglier and uglier.

Is there a way that I can declare my function which simply promises to return something that can be iterated as a `CollectionType<Mapping>`?

Trying to use `CollectionType<Mapping>` yields:

> Cannot specialize non-generic type 'CollectionType'

Trying to use `CollectionType` gives me the error that:

> Protocol 'CollectionType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what type erasers are for. In this case you're looking for `AnyForwardCollection`:

```
public func mappingsWithElementId(elementId:String) -> AnyForwardCollection<Mapping> {
    return AnyForwardCollection(_mappings.lazy.map({ $1 }).filter({ $0.elementId == elementId }))
}
```

There are a bunch of others. `AnySequence`, `AnyRandomAccessCollection`, etc. You can create your own if you like, as well. See [A Little Respect for AnySequence](http://robnapier.net/erasure) for more on that.